# Unable to run android maps app on emulator

Tags: android

my program starts on emulator but it close with showing msg sorry the application location (pacakge name) has stopped unexpectedly .please try again.
i am using google api 2.3.3 emulator for runing this apps

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an error in your program causing an exception which terminates the activity. Check the logcat for exception details